# How to adding nested dictionaries & collection in VBA/Json Ms Access 2016

Tags: json, vba, dictionary

Our company require to send invoices details for assessment to our Tax consultant in Json format, this means every invoice generated must pass through the Tax consultant for authentication. If an invoice is not correctly generated the Tax consultant send it back as rejected. The problem here we are not able to get the correct Json format after exporting Ms access 2016 invoices data

I have a code below which is almost complete for exporting Ms Access data into the correct Json format, but I’m the following two things below:
Current Json format:

```
{
"PosSerialNumber":"",
"IssueTime":"",
"TransactionType":0,
"PaymentMode":0,
"SaleType":0,
"Items":{
"ItemId":1,
"Description":"Apple"
"Barcode":"458630036",
"Quantity":8,
"UnitPrice":2,
"Discount":0,
"Taxable":[
"A",
"T"
]
}
}
```

The following two things below:
(1) As you can see its missing a square bracket on "Items":{ , the correct one is supposed to be "Items":[{ as well as the closing ] 
(2) I want to add also (“Total”,120, “IstaxInclusive”: true) so that the final code should look like below:

Below is the current MS Access VBA code we are using to try and achieve the required goal

VBA code used to generate the above Json format:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim foo As New Dictionary
Set foo = New Dictionary
Dim Noor As Dictionary
Set Noor = New Dictionary
Dim hoo As New Collection
Dim goo As New Dictionary
Set goo = New Dictionary
Dim Zoo As New Dictionary
Set Zoo = New Dictionary
Dim Koo As New Collection
Dim json As String
    With foo
        .Add "PosSerialNumber", Me.txtchris
        .Add "IssueTime", Me.txtAddress
        .Add "TransactionTyp", 0
        .Add "PaymentMode", 0
        .Add "SaleType", 0
        .Add "Items", Noor
     Noor.Add "ItemID", 1
     Noor.Add "Description", "Apple"
     Noor.Add "BarCode", "4589630036"
     Noor.Add "Quantity", 8
     Noor.Add "UnitPrice", 2
     Noor.Add "Discount", 0
     Noor.Add "Taxable", hoo
     hoo.Add "A"
     hoo.Add "T"

    End With

    Dim member As Variant
    For Each member In foo

    Next
MsgBox JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(foo, Whitespace:=3), vbOKOnly, "Audited by C H"
```

End Sub

Required format:

```
{
"PosSerialNumber":"",
"IssueTime":"",
"TransactionType":0,
"PaymentMode":0,
"SaleType":0,
"Items":[{
"ItemId":1,
"Description":"Apple"
"Barcode":"458630036",
"Quantity":8,
"UnitPrice":2,
"Discount":0,
"Taxable":[
"A",
"T"
]
"Total":120,
"IsTaxInclusive":true,
"SP":0
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets in JSON indicate an Array.  `JsonConverter` will wrap collection or Arrays  in `[]`.
You can either wrap `Noor` in an `Array()` or add it to a collection 
Array

> ```
> .Add "Items", Array(Noor)
> ```

Collection

> ```
> Dim NoorCollection As New Collection
> NoorCollection.Add Noor
> .Add "Items", NoorCollection
> ```

[image: Immediate Window]